# How to find the derivative of the following vectors and matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

*I am stuck on the following two questions on matrix Algebra:*

Let $x$ be a vector. Find the following:

- $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}||x\otimes x||^2$, here ||.|| denotes Euclidean norm of a vector and $\otimes$ denotes the kroneckar product.
- $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^T}(\frac{x}{||x||})$.

**My try**:
**(i)**
Let us take $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$.
Then $x\otimes x=\begin{pmatrix}x_1^2 &x_1x_2& x_1x_3 &\dots & x_1x_n
\\
x_2x_1 &x_2^2& x_2x_3 &\dots & x_2x_n
\\
\dots & \dots& \dots & \dots & \dots\\
\dots & \dots& \dots & \dots & \dots\\
x_nx_1 &x_nx_2& x_nx_3 &\dots & x_n^2
\end{pmatrix}$

I am confused about how do I take $||x\otimes x||$ and find its derivative in terms of $x$.

**(II)** Since $||x||$ is a scalar, so we can write $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^T}(\frac{x}{||x||})=\frac{1}{||x||}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^T}(x)$.
Here I am stuck how to find the derivative of $x$ with respect to $x^T$.

Can someone please help me to clear my doubts and complete the above problems?

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different approach is to
note that the function you
want to differentiate can be written as
$$
\phi
= \| \mathbf{x} \otimes \mathbf{x} \|_2^2
= \| \mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^T \|^2_F
$$

The differential writes
$$
d\phi 
= 2 \mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^T:d(\mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^T)
= 4 \mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x}:d\mathbf{x}
$$
The gradient is thus
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{x}}
= 4 \| \mathbf{x} \|_2^2 \mathbf{x}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}\def\l{\lambda}\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\B{\Big}\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\B(#1\B)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\v#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\t{\otimes}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$The Frobenius product is a concise notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
This is also called the double-dot or double contraction product.

When applied to vectors $(n=\o)$ it reduces to the standard dot product.

The distributive rule for a mixed Kronecker-Frobenius product is
$$\eqalign{
(A\t B):(X\t Y) = (A:X)\t(B:Y) \\
}$$

First calculate the gradient of the simple function
$$\eqalign{
\a &= \|x\|^2 = x:x \qiq \c{d\a = 2x:dx} \\
}$$
Then calculate the differential (and gradient)
for the first function of interest $(\b)$.
$$\eqalign{
\b &= \|x\t x\|^2 \\&= (x\t x):(x\t x) \\&= (x:x)\t(x:x) \\&= \a^2 \\
d\b &= 2\a\;\c{d\a} \\&= 2\a\,\LR{2x\,dx} \\&= 4\|x\|^2\,x\,dx \\
\grad{\b}{x} &= 4\|x\|^2\,x \\
}$$
The second function of interest $(y)$
can also make use of the simple $\a$ function.
$$\eqalign{
\l &= \|x\| \\
\l^2 &= \a \qiq 2\l\,d\l = d\a = 2x^Tdx \\
d\l &= \l^{-1}x^Tdx \\
\\
y &= \frac{x}{\|x\|} = \l^{-1}x \\
dy &= \l^{-1}dx-x\l^{-2}\,\c{d\l} \\
 &= \l^{-1}I\,dx-x\l^{-2}\,\c{\l^{-1}x^Tdx} \\
 &= \l^{-1}\LR{I-yy^T}\,dx \\
\grad{y}{x} &= \l^{-1}\LR{I-yy^T} \\\\
}$$

---

**NB:** Your expansion of $(x\t x)$ is incorrect. What you have
written is actually the matrix $xx^T$ which you must
[vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) to recover the desired Kronecker product, i.e.
$$(x\t x) = \v{xx^T}$$
However, there is another property of the Frobenius product
$$\v{A}:\v{A} = A:A$$
which allows you to use your matrix without vectorizing it
$$\eqalign{
\b &= \v{xx^T}:\v{xx^T} \\&= \LR{xx^T}:\LR{xx^T} \\
 &= \trace{xx^Txx^T} \\&= \a^2
}$$